# How to add button to title bar?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am making an android app. I need to add a button to the title bar of an activity. I cannot put it in the action bar because of backward compatibility problems. I searched a lot but couldn't find a satisfactory solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: You want to add a BUTTON into a TITLE BAR? Even if this is possible (I'm sure it is), it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Ahmad Why is it not a good idea? iOS apps have it all the time..

Comment: The correct answer is to use the action bar. You may wish to ask a separate StackOverflow question regarding your "backward compatibility problems".

Comment: @vergilcorleone It's juts a narrow bar and not really intended to have buttons and other UI elements in it (besides the title)

Comment: @CommonsWare Action bar requires API level 11 to work, my app's minimum is 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Action bar requires API level 11 to work, my app's minimum is 9

Use a backport, like [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), which offers action bars back to API Level 7. More importantly, it does so using an API compatible with the official action bar implementation, and so dropping ActionBarSherlock in a year or two (when you drop support for API Level 9-10) will be fairly easy. And, your app will have a consistent look and feel with other Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar and created a custom title bar as follows:

- Create a custom View class (I extended linearlayout)
- Add this view to the layout xml of your activity, in the top
- Hide the default bar, using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` (if I remember correctly, it is crucial to do this *before* setting the content view of your activity).